# Smart way to insert in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter, and I have a large table with a lot of columns that I want to insert large amount of data into. Is there a better approach than writing the name if each column, and then the value that will be inserted in each column. For example, a php function that gets the table columns and put them in an array, and have another array that have the values pointing to each column...

Example with codeigniter:

```
$data = array('column_name1'=>'value1', 'column_name2' =>'value2'....);
$this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
```

Regular php

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (column_name1, column_name2) VALUES ("Value1"....)");
```

Comment: Just how many columns are you talking about? It would probably have been easier to just type them out than to type out this question.

Comment: multiple tables with at least between 30 to 40 columns

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated.

Comment: Dynamic prepared statements: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13333344/1322435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside model constructor I will instantiate a property and I'll store there my columns names. I'll reuse that array many times so that's why it's in the constructor

```
$this->table_col = $this->db->list_fields('table_name');
```

Inside the insert method, with an array like this as parameter

```
$data = array(
   array('column_name1'=>'value1', 'column_name2' =>'value2'....),
   array('column_name1'=>'value1', 'column_name2' =>'value2'....),
   array('column_name1'=>'value1', 'column_name2' =>'value2'....)
);
```

I will filter columns removing each invalid field. You can wrap it in a function since you'll use it in other places (update, insert_single, where clauses)

```
 foreach($data as &$single)
 {
     $invalid_keys = array_diff(array_keys($single), $this->table_col);

     if(!empty($invalid_keys))
     {
        $single = array_diff_key($single,array_flip($invalid_keys));
     }
 }
```

If I want to be sure that each query went well, I'll use transactions. Otherwise just insert_batch

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->insert_batch('table_name', $data); 

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your example of data:

```
$data = array('column_name1'=>'value1', 'column_name2' =>'value2'....);
$this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
```

You could build your query like this:

```
private function buildInsertSql($data, $table) {
    $columns = "";  
    $holders = "";  
    foreach ($data as $column => $value) {  
       $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "" : ", ";  
       $columns .= $column;  
       $holders .= ($holders == "") ? "" : ", ";  
       $holders .= ":$column";  
    }  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($holders)";  
    return $sql; 
}
```

You should then run it using PDO, since `mysql_query` is deprecated.
You can read up on how PDO binds values to 'holders', etc.
Also, don't forget other forms of sanitization, like white-listing your column names etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data); 

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date'), ('Another title', 'Another name', 'Another date')
```

Source: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Or this just could serve as a base to be extended then

------------EDIT AFTER 1st COMMENT-------------

So to get yourtablename columns you can apply something like this with Active Record Class methods in CI

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name='Yourtablename'
```

This way you can create columns array as you described and proceed with it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I'm trying to avoid typing the name of the columns because I have many tables with about 30 to 40 columns

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array('column_name1'=>'value1', 'column_name2' =>'value2'....);

foreach($data as $key as $value){
 $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($key) VALUES ($value)";  
    return $sql; 
}
```

...I hope i give you idea :)